# R shinydashboard menu items and subitems reactive output is shown in one tab

Tags: r, output, shinydashboard, dt, reactive

I am fairly new to `Shiny`, `shinydashboard` and `DT`. I am trying to build a simple application where I load data from `.csv` file, generated like this:

```
x <- data.table(VAR1 = rnorm(n = 20, mean = 10, sd = 2), VAR2 = rnorm(n = 20, mean = 100, sd = 20), VAR3 = 1:20, VAR4 = 21:40)
write.csv(x = x, file = "/tmp/test_data.csv")
```

I have built the application where I have a dashboard with two menu items (`Data` and `My Items`), the second one has three subitems. The first menu item (`Data`) has "Browse" button is loading the data and show it in a `DT` table. The subitems in the second menu item (`My Items`) should show output only when the data is loaded. Each of them should show a heading and a `DT` table with two of the variables in the loaded data set. However, when the data is loaded, all the outputs are shown in the first tab and the tabs for the subitems of the second menu item remain empty.

When there is no reactive input ([like in this simple example](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#sidebar-menu-items-and-tabs)) everything works fine, but with reactive output things seem different. Apparently, there are still things that I fail to understand. Can someone help?

Here is the application:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(title = "Dashboard Title",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(id = "menu",
                                  menuItem(text = "Data", icon = icon("database"), tabName = "inputData",
                                           fileInput(inputId = "file", label = "Choose CSV File",
                                                     multiple = TRUE,
                                                     accept = ".csv")),
                                  menuItem(text = "My Items", tabName = "items", icon = icon("book"),
                                           menuSubItem(text = "Item 1", tabName = "item01"),
                                           menuSubItem(text = "Item 2", tabName = "item02"),
                                           menuSubItem(text = "Item 3", tabName = "item03")
                                  )
                      )
                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "inputData", class = "active",
                                h1(textOutput("heading")),
                                dataTableOutput("loaded.data")),
                        tabItem(tabName = "items", h1(textOutput("heading0")), class = "active",
                                tabItem(tabName = "item01", class = "active", h1(textOutput("heading1")), dataTableOutput("table1")),
                                tabItem(tabName = "item02", class = "active", h1(textOutput("heading2")), dataTableOutput("table2")),
                                tabItem(tabName = "item03", class = "active", h1(textOutput("heading3")), dataTableOutput("table3"))
                        )
                      )
                    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Load the data and assign it to a reactive object
  df <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file
    if(is.null(inFile)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      tbl <- fread(input$file$datapath, sep = ",", quote = '"', stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
      return(tbl)
    }
  })

  output$heading <- renderText({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      return("Data loaded")
    }
  })

  output$loaded.data <- renderDT({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      df()
    }
  })

  output$heading0 <- renderText({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      return("In the sub-menus below you will find the tables")
    }
  })

  output$heading1 <- renderText({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      return("Heading item 1")
    }
  })

  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      return(df()[ , c("VAR1", "VAR2")])
    }
  })

  output$heading2 <- renderText({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      return("Heading item 2")
    }
  })

  output$table2 <- renderDT({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      return(df()[ , c("VAR2", "VAR3")])
    }
  })

  output$heading3 <- renderText({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      return("Heading item 3")
    }
  })

  output$table3 <- renderDT({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      return(df()[ , c("VAR2", "VAR3")])
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should write your `dashboardBody` as  follows:

```
dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "inputData", 
            h1(textOutput("heading")),
            dataTableOutput("loaded.data")),
    tabItem(tabName = "item01", 
            h1(textOutput("heading1")), 
            dataTableOutput("table1")),
    tabItem(tabName = "item02", 
            h1(textOutput("heading2")), 
            dataTableOutput("table2")),
    tabItem(tabName = "item03",
            h1(textOutput("heading3")), 
            dataTableOutput("table3"))  
  )
)
```

**EDIT**

Doing so, the full table does not appear anymore. To solve this issue, my proposal is to add a new `menuSubItem` in `dashboardSidebar` for the full table as follows:

```
dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = "menu",
              menuItem(text = "Data", icon = icon("database"), 
                       fileInput(inputId = "file", label = "Choose CSV File",
                                 multiple = TRUE,
                                 accept = ".csv"),
                       menuSubItem(text = "Full Table", tabName = "inputData")
              ),
              menuItem(text = "My Items",  icon = icon("book"),
                       menuSubItem(text = "Item 1", tabName = "item01"),
                       menuSubItem(text = "Item 2", tabName = "item02"),
                       menuSubItem(text = "Item 3", tabName = "item03")
              )
  )
)
```

Or a bit nicer (IMHO):

```
dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = "menu",
              menuItem(text = "Data", icon = icon("database"), 
                       fileInput(inputId = "file", label = "Choose CSV File",
                                 multiple = TRUE,
                                 accept = ".csv")
              ),
              menuItem(text = "My Items",  icon = icon("book"),
                       menuSubItem(text = "Full Table", tabName = "inputData"),
                       menuSubItem(text = "Item 1", tabName = "item01"),
                       menuSubItem(text = "Item 2", tabName = "item02"),
                       menuSubItem(text = "Item 3", tabName = "item03")
              )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you DJack, this is going somewhere, but now the data set is not shown in the `Menu` tab, instead `table01` and its heading appear there. `table03` is not shown in its subitem tab, neither its heading. `table01` and `table02` and ther headings appear at their places.

Comment: Read the end of the answer for table03. I am trying to figure out for the full table

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad, I was so excited that I did not read the full answer. I also corrected the example here.

Comment: Not a problem. I made an edit to the answer with a proposal to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves the problem. Have to read all your code to understand it, I am really new to Shiny. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. I have  removed `class="active"` and `tabName` for `menuItem` as both are not needed. If you think it solved your problem, consider accepting the answer to close the question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).